# How do I get the last 4 characters of a String using Java for excutable jar file?

Tags: java, jar

The compiler shows this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    length cannot be resolved or is not a field

    at SeperatorTool.Seperator.main(Seperator.java:23)
```

I think the error is here,

```
    String fileName = readFile.getName();
    String[] nameArr = fileName.substring(fileName.length -5);
    String asnName = nameArr[1];
```

Here is my full code;

```
package SeperatorTool;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Seperator
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException
  {
String baseDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File sourcePath = new File(baseDir);
File[] arrayOfFile;
int j = (arrayOfFile = sourcePath.listFiles()).length;
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
  File readFile = arrayOfFile[i];
  if ((readFile.isFile()) && 
    (!readFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("seperatortool.jar")) && (!readFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(".project")) && (!readFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(".settings")) && (!readFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(".classpath")))
  {
    String fileName = readFile.getName();
    String[] nameArr = fileName.substring(fileName.length -5);
    String asnName = nameArr[1];
    File asnDir = new File(baseDir + File.separator + asnName);
    if ((!asnDir.exists()) || (!asnDir.isDirectory())) {
      asnDir.mkdir();
    }
    readFile.renameTo(new File(baseDir + File.separator + asnName + File.separator + readFile.getName()));
  }
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: use filename.length(), not fileName.length

Comment: JavaScript Should not be confused with Java

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: it happens in file Seperator.java at line 23 and the problem is that "length cannot be resolved or is not a field". Learn to read and understand error messages, they give valuable information about the problem.

Comment: I changed and checked . but still not working.

Comment: yes. Length is not a field. how we will get the output for this code from java

Comment: I tried with java script in java code but not work in java. which one i use to get the result .

Comment: can anyone correct  my coed ?

Comment: I recommend you to use IDE like eclipse, netbeans, etc... IDE will point out code issues before you run the code.

Answer (score 0):

As @muzzlator pointed out use `fileName.length()` instead `fileName.length`. Also `String[] nameArr = fileName.substring(fileName.length -5);` will return `String` not `String[]`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SO42992920 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String baseDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File sourcePath = new File(baseDir);
        File[] arrayOfFile;
        int j = (arrayOfFile = sourcePath.listFiles()).length;
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            File readFile = arrayOfFile[i];
            if ((readFile.isFile()) && (!readFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("seperatortool.jar"))
                    && (!readFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(".project"))
                    && (!readFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(".settings"))
                    && (!readFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(".classpath"))) {
                String fileName = readFile.getName();
                String nameString = fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 5);

                System.out.println(nameString);

                /* Change your code */
//              String asnName = nameArr[1];
//              File asnDir = new File(baseDir + File.separator + asnName);
//              if ((!asnDir.exists()) || (!asnDir.isDirectory())) {
//                  asnDir.mkdir();
//              }
//              readFile.renameTo(new File(baseDir + File.separator + asnName + File.separator + readFile.getName()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vicky Thakor. It is working.but, includes file format also.I don't want that.   for Example. I separate jpg file name kalaiselvan. out put is like ., "n.jpg" instead of "lvan"